# In python requests library, cannot do authorization?

Tags: php, python, curl, python-requests

I try to wrote this code on python:
http://vestacp.com/docs/api/#add_user

like this:
http://pastebin.com/XdzKKZpg

but I cant authorize

Comment: include the code in your question too! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your last line, `auth` is missing the '`=`' sign:

```
req = r.post(vst_hostname, auth(vst_username, vst_hostname), \
        params=postvars, verify=False)
```

See the [authentication section in the `requests` documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
r.post(vst_hostname, auth(vst_username, vst_hostname), params=postvars, verify=False)
```

You're doing the equivalent of

```
r.post(vst_hostname, data=auth(vst_username, vst_hostname), params=postvars, verify=False)
```

And you want to be doing

```
r.post(vst_hostname, auth=auth(vst_username, vst_hostname), params=postvars, verify=False)
```

Further, you can simplify this. You do not need to explicitly say `HTTPBasicAuth(vst_username, vst_hostname)`, instead you can simply pass a tuple like so:

```
r.post(vst_hostname, auth=(vst_username, vst_hostname), params=postvars, verify=False)
```

I'm also unfamiliar with how that PHP code works, so you will want to be cognizant of the fact that `params=postvars` creates query string parameters so it'll be the same as doing a `POST` to

```
https://188.188.188.88/api?cmd=v-add-user&arg1=...&arg2=...
```

If instead that data should be in the *body* of the request you'll want to do:

```
r.post(vst_hostname, auth=(vst_username, vst_hostname), data=postvars, verify=False)
```